# Converting float to int without rounding

Tags: objective-c

I want to convert a decimal number to an int without rounding it, for example:
if the number is 3.9 it will be turned into 3 (if it would have been rounded it would be 4).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generally don't need to do anything special, as by default a cast from float/double to an integer type results in truncation:

```
float f = 3.9f;
int i = (int)f; // i = 3
```

Comment: It's incorrect. For example, if you have `float a = 1.2f` and use loop to sum up a for 100 times, you'll get a float 119.99. Then you cast it in that way, and you'll get 119, not 120

Comment: @Eric: I think you're missing the point of the question - the OP requires *truncation*, so 119.99 *should* give 119.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you want the negative values be treated. Typecasting to int would just truncate in that way that the part left of the decimal point will remain. -3.9f would turn into -3. Using floor before casting would ensure that it results in -4. 
(all within the variable type boundaries of course)

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this bellow :-

```
float myFloat = 3.9;


    int result1 = (int)ceilf(myFloat );
NSLog(@"%d",result1);

    int result2 = (int)roundf(myFloat );
NSLog(@"%d",result2);

    int result3 = (int)floor(myFloat);
NSLog(@"%d",result3);

int result4 = (int) (myFloat);

NSLog(@"%d",result4);
```

**OUTPUT IS** 
4
4
3
3

Comment: It is just that he does not want 4 as the output. He seeks for 3.

Comment: Looks better. Do the same for -3.9 in case he has to consider negative values too and he's got a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the float to an int and it will truncate your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple typecast to int